# Security issue with tiny browser

Tags: php, tinymce

I have used [tinybrowser](http://www.lunarvis.com/products/tinymcefilebrowserwithupload.php) with tiny mce as a plugin (My panel is php based).
When uploading, there is link like this:

```
www.****.com/dashboard/tiny_mce/plugins/tinybrowser/tinybrowser.php?type=image
```

This link can open in all browser without permission. 
What is the solution in this case? Could I use my admin panel's session control in tinyMce plugins??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this:

in config_tinybrowser.php you have to uncomment and configure this lines:

```
if(isset($_GET['sessidpass'])) session_id($_GET['sessidpass']); // workaround for Flash session bug
session_start();
$tinybrowser['sessioncheck'] = 'good-user'; //name of session variable to check
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll take advantage of the panel session in order to not allow users to get there without authorization. I guess you already have some scripts tha control that, so it'd be as easy as include them where you want to secure your app.